# @NgModule missing after typescript upgrade

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I have an angular application, using typescript `2.2.0` and working fine.

Lately I decided to add a library for serialization: `@kaiu/ng-serializer`.

But this library requires TS 2.4+ to run properly, so I decided to upgrade my typescript in package.json to `2.5.1`.

After I upgraded typescript (and changed 0 lines of code), I get this runtime error (compilation is fine) after I start the project with `ng serve`:

> Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'CoreModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

The `AppModule` can be found on [Github](https://github.com/Supamiu/ffxiv-teamcraft/blob/refactoring/src/app/app.module.ts)

Here is the list of my dependencies with typescript upgraded to `2.5.1`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/common": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/core": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/http": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/router": "^4.3.2",
    "@kaiu/ng-serializer": "^1.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^7.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/jwt-decode": "^1.4.28",
    "angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^4.2.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.3.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "husky": "^0.14.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "standard-version": "^4.2.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "2.5.1"
}
```

Comment: Show your `AppModule`

Comment: @SurenSrapyan I added a link to the app.module.ts file on github, I made no changes to code, it feels like I have to change some configuration to upgrade TS to 2.5 but I can't find which one(s).

Comment: Is this the project? https://github.com/Supamiu/ffxiv-teamcraft/blob/master/src/tsconfig.app.json

Comment: https://github.com/Supamiu/ffxiv-teamcraft/blob/1b78876a84b976a4e1f1974900b8d1efee6cec48/src/tsconfig.app.json#L15  

Could this line be the problem? Shouldnt the metadata be emitted?